# Can't install pyautogui due to psyscreeze FilenotFoundError: 'README.md'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-7-x64, pyautogui

Installed Anaconda right now, so python 3.6
Could install other packages, but for some reason can't pyautogui. I have pillow installed already.
I  have to use these 'trusted host' and 'proxy' due to workplace.

```
(base) C:\>pip install --proxy [snipped website] --trusted-host pypi.
python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org pyautogui
Collecting pyautogui
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/70/c5d340fadb06106135b7
fe9677fc6d275f3cd7f7e6f896316c4cfe6c022c/PyAutoGUI-0.9.37.tar.gz (47kB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 51kB 379kB/s
Collecting pymsgbox (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/65/86379ede1db26c40e797
2d7a41c69cdf12cc6a0f143749aabf67ab8a41a1/PyMsgBox-1.0.6.zip
Collecting PyTweening>=1.0.1 (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/f8/c32a58d6e4dff8aa5c27
e907194d69f3b57e525c2e4af96f39c6e9c854d2/PyTweening-1.0.3.zip
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\krmeszar\appdata\local\continu
um\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui) (5.1.0)
Collecting pyscreeze (from pyautogui)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/6e/e175fda37d76d7846a6c
da8a4364dfd7c2d343139b0716c4f03194d14933/PyScreeze-0.1.17.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\[snipped name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jmkbzjm3\pyscreeze\
setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\[snipped name]
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jmkbzjm3\pyscreeze\
```

Thought it might be a problem with pyscreeze, but can't install it either.

```
(base) C:\>pip install --proxy [snipped website] --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org pyscreeze
Collecting pyscreeze
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/6e/e175fda37d76d7846a6c
da8a4364dfd7c2d343139b0716c4f03194d14933/PyScreeze-0.1.17.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\[snipped name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ymkt05sy\pyscreeze\
setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.md'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\[snipped  name]\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ymkt05sy\pyscreeze\
```

Any idea what is the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new release (v0.1.17) of pyscreeze fails to install.

As workaround try to install first the last working version of pyscreeze and after this pyautogui:

```
pip install pyscreeze==0.1.14
pip install PyAutoGUI
```

I already created a new ticket for this issue https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/issues/37

EDIT:
The new version of pyscreeze seems to work, in fact you can install pyautogui again

```
pip install -U pyautogui
```